# model selection for GaussianMixture by using GridSearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'd like to use the function GaussianMixture by scikit-learn, and I have to perform model selection.
I want to do it by using GridSearchCV, and I would like to use for the selection the BIC and the AIC.
Both these values are implemented into GaussianMixture(), but I don't know how to insert them into the definition of my custom scorer, since the function

```
make_scorer(score_func, greater_is_better=True, needs_proba=False, needs_threshold=False, **kwargs)
```

that I am using to create my custom scorer takes as input a function score_funct, that has to be defined as

```
score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: May I ask why you are using the BIC or AIC? I would recommend using cross validation instead. Also, I assume you are using GridSearchCV to decide on the number of Gaussians to use?

Comment: Yes, I am also using GridSearchCV for the number of Gaussians.
I am at the real beginning of my analysis and I am trying many things, and I found out that BIC and AIC are two possible ways.
I am using GaussianMixture for anomaly detection, I don't know if this helps.

Comment: I will post an answer that details how to fit using GridSearchCV, and also how to use the BIC or the AIC.

Comment: thanks a lot, looking forward to it.

Comment: thought i'd be relatively thorough. hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Using the BIC/AIC is an *alternative* to using cross validation. `GridSearchCV` selects models using cross validation. To perform model selection using the BIC/AIC we have to do something a little different. Let's take an example where we generate samples from two Gaussians, and then try to fit them using scikit-learn.

```
import numpy as np
X1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0.,0.],[[1.,0.],[0.,1.]],10000)
X2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([10.,10.],[[1.,0.],[0.,1.]],10000)
X = np.vstack((X1,X2))
np.random.shuffle(X)
```

[image]

**Method 1: Cross-validation**

[Cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_%28statistics%29) involves splitting the data into pieces. One then fits the model on some of the pieces ('training') and tests how well it performs on the remaining pieces ('validating'). This guards against over-fitting. Here we will use two-fold cross validation, where we split the data in half.

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#check 1->4 components
tuned_parameters = {'n_components': np.array([1,2,3,4])}
#construct grid search object that uses 2 fold cross validation
clf = GridSearchCV(GaussianMixture(),tuned_parameters,cv=2)
#fit the data
clf.fit(X)
#plot the number of Gaussians against their rank
plt.scatter(clf.cv_results_['param_n_components'],\
            clf.cv_results_['rank_test_score'])
```

We can see that 2-fold cross validation favours two Gaussian components, as we expect.

[image]

**Method 2: BIC/AIC**

Instead of using cross-validation, we can evaluate the [BIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion) using the best-fit model given each number of Gaussians. We then choose the model that has the lowest BIC. The procedure would be identical if one used the AIC (although it is a different statistic, and can provide different answers: but your code structure would be identical to below).

```
bic = np.zeros(4)
n = np.arange(1,5)
models = []
#loop through each number of Gaussians and compute the BIC, and save the model
for i,j in enumerate(n):
    #create mixture model with j components
    gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=j)
    #fit it to the data
    gmm.fit(X)
    #compute the BIC for this model
    bic[i] = gmm.bic(X)
    #add the best-fit model with j components to the list of models
    models.append(gmm)
```

After carrying out this procedure, we can plot the number of Gaussians against the BIC.

```
plt.plot(n,bic)
```

[image]

So we can see that the BIC is minimised for two Gaussians, so the best model 
according to this method also has two components.

Because I took 10000 samples from two very well-separated Gaussians (i.e. the distance between their centres is much larger than either of their dispersions), the answer was very clear-cut. This is not always the case, and often neither of these methods will confidently tell you which number of Gaussians to use, but rather some sensible range.

Comment: thanks a lot for the excellent explanation.
The point was wheter it is possible to use GridSearchCV to select the model by using BIC (or AIC), instead of using the for cycle.

Comment: Yes, but `GridSearchCV` is specifically designed for cross validation. Cross validation is an *alternative* to the BIC/AIC, and so using the BIC/AIC with `GridSearchCV` doesn't really make sense. One should use one or the other.

Comment: Section 3.2.4.2 of [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) explains that you can use information criteria instead of cross validation in some cases, but it only seems to be explicitly implemented for `linear_model.LassoLarsIC`, so one has to use a `for` loop for `GaussianMixture` as I did above. I've edited my answer to make this all a bit clearer. Does this help?

Comment: my idea was to define a custom scorer with the BIC by using the function `make_scorer` that I mentioned in the post.
The point is that apparently this function takes in input a function score_funct (that should be my BIC), but score_funct should be defined as `score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)`; I would like to exploit (as you did in your loop) the attribute .bic defined in GaussianMixture(), but I don't know hot to do it. (I don't know whether I made my question clearer)

Comment: I think I understand what you were asking, it's just that `GridSearchCV` is inappropriate because you *have* to use some kind of cross-validation when you use it. When you choose models with BIC/AIC, you use *all* of the data, instead of subsamples. So you can't use `GridSearchCV`, which demands that you subdivide the data and cross-validate. Hence the `for` loop is the best approach for BIC/AIC. Does this make sense?